# The maximum number of UserPropaties in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

The maximum number of UserPropaties is 25,
Is this the upper limit you can display on the console?
Is it possible to check even if it exceeds 25 from BigQuery etc.?

[This is the link of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Analytics for Firebase SDKs, back-end and console are all limited to having at most 25 user properties. This is not just limited to the console. Any additional properties will also not be exported to BigQuery.